# This code is running perfectly in codeblocks but giving a runtime error on ideone.com

Tags: c++, gcc, gnu

```
int main()
{

    long int n,x,cost[100];
    cin>>n>>x;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cin>>cost[i];

    int i=0,flag=0,s=0,first;
    first=cost[0];
    while(i<n)
    {
       s+=cost[i];
       if(s>x){
           s-=first;
           first++;
       }
       if(s==x)
       {
           flag=1;
           break;
       } 
       i++;
    }
    if(flag==0) cout<<"no";
    else cout<<"yes";
}
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/U272Yc)

This code is a problem from hackerearth. Name of the problem is 'Prateek and his friends'
Please help.

Comment: Think about what happens if the only input is an "end of file", which is what happens when there's no standard input in Ideone. What value do you think your variables will have?

Comment: http://ideone.com/WUk0dE

Comment: Btw, did you try this for more than the *one* trivial test case?

Comment: Compile at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_cpp_online.php its running fine here

Comment: what about if `n > 100` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is your only error, but you should always ensure that integer variables have been assigned to, (unless you don't end up using them)
In this case a sensible default might be `long int n = 0, x = 0`.

In addition, `cin>>n` will not work properly if it can't read from the stream (due to EOF) you should probably check after doing a read that it succeeded, use `cin.fail()`, if it returns `true` than the previous operation (or a one before that) failed.

I don't actually recall dealing with the possibility of a stream read failing before, so I may be wrong/missed something